# Change border color of buttons once pressed

Tags: css, objective-c, button, background, border

I am trying to have the borders for the buttons change once buttons are pressed, here is how the code currently looks:

```
[m_btnEthinic addObject:btnEthnicity1];
[m_btnEthinic addObject:btnEthnicity2];
[m_btnEthinic addObject:btnEthnicity3];
[m_btnEthinic addObject:btnEthnicity4];
[m_btnEthinic addObject:btnEthnicity5];
[m_btnEthinic addObject:btnEthnicity6];
[m_btnEthinic addObject:btnEthnicity7];
[m_btnEthinic addObject:btnEthnicity8];
[m_btnEthinic addObject:btnEthnicity9];
for (UIButton* btn in m_btnEthinic) {
    btn.layer.borderWidth = 1;
    btn.layer.cornerRadius = 13;
    btn.layer.borderColor = COLOR_GRAYBORDERBTN.CGColor;
    [btn setBackgroundColor: COLOR_PURP];
    [btn setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal]
```

Comment: these **btnEthnicity** are created by programmatically or with storyboard?

Comment: They were made on Storyboard

Comment: then you can try with  **IBOutletCollection** NSArray with conditions

Answer (score 1):

With storyboard, you can do like this:

- drag and place the button into viewcontroller
- set the button **Tag** as per the buttons
- drag the buttons into `.h` and create **IBOutletCollection** NSArray for buttons. Link all buttons into same outlet.
  `@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *btn;`
- set **IBAction** common for all the buttons.
  `- (IBAction)btnActions:(UIButton *)sender;`

[image: common IBAction for uibutton]

- once created **IBAction**, `btnActions:` method will be created in `.m`

```c
-(IBAction) btnActions: (UIButton * ) sender {

  for (UIButton * b in self.btn) {
    //checking if already have borders for the buttons
    if (b.layer.cornerRadius == 13) {
      b.layer.borderWidth = 0;
      b.layer.cornerRadius = 0;
    }

    //setting the borders for the selected button
    if (b.tag == sender.tag) {
      b.layer.borderWidth = 2;
      b.layer.cornerRadius = 13;
      b.layer.borderColor = [UIColor yellowColor].CGColor;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a selector to you button, and use a BOOL property to track the button status and witch the color in the selector. If you have an array of buttons you will need an array of status flags. The code below should work (sorry for any typo. I am not in front of my computer at this time).

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) borderStatus;

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    borderStatus = NO;
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

 -(void)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
        if(borderStatus){
              ((UIButton*)sender).layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor];
              borderStatus = NO;
        } else {
              ((UIButton*)sender).layer.borderColor = [UIColor greenColor];
              borderStatus = YES;
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

will, I guess you maybe need this. You can add two events for the buttons. So set border when the event `UIControlEventTouchDown` response, and recover it when the event `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`response.

All this on my Github  name 'T_yunButtonBorder' git@github.com:xmy0010/DemoForCSDN.git

Like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

     NSMutableArray *m_btnEthinic = @[].mutableCopy;
     for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {

         UIButton *btnEthnicity = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
         [btnEthnicity setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"btn%d", i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
         btnEthnicity.frame = CGRectMake(50, 50 + 40 * i, 50, 20);
         btnEthnicity.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
         [btnEthnicity addTarget:self action:@selector(btnEthnicityTouchDown:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchDown];
         [btnEthnicity addTarget:self action:@selector(btnEthnicityTouchUp:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
         [self.view addSubview:btnEthnicity];
         [m_btnEthinic addObject:btnEthnicity];
     }
}


- (void)btnEthnicityTouchDown:(UIButton *)sender {

    NSLog(@"down");
    sender.layer.borderWidth = 2;
    sender.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
    sender.layer.borderColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
}

- (void)btnEthnicityTouchUp:(UIButton *)sender {

    NSLog(@"up");
    sender.layer.borderWidth = 0;
    sender.layer.cornerRadius = 0;
}
```